# How to make a background in a container and put the text in the middle of the photo? HTML/ CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am learning HTML/ CSS and JS. I am making my first website and I have a problem. How can I change the background in the container under the pictures, to my color. On the internet I only find `bg-secondary` etc and I need for example #82b5cf.

I also have a question, I want to put the text in the middle of the picture, now it is under the photo and I can't do anything with it, for a test I changed the font and there is no reaction. Thank you very much for your help :)

```css
main {
  .aboutus-card-title {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="UAV" class="...."> //#82b5cf
    <div class="container ">
      <div class="row gx-4 ">
        <div class="col-sm ">
          <img class="uav-photo" src="img/introduction_1.jpg" alt="An orange four-engine drone hovers in the clear blue sky.">
          <p class="aboutus-card-title">Introduction</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <img class="uav-photo" src="img/UAV_features_2.jpg" alt="An orange four-engine drone hovers in the clear blue sky.">
          <p class="aboutus-card-title">Elements</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background). Do you compile SASS?

Comment: Yes, I do compile in the SASS

Comment: _"I put the text in the middle of the photo, it is under the photo and I can't do anything with it"_ the image element and the paragraph are two distinct elements rendered with their own position. How did you expect them to be rendered instead? And in general failing at changing the background style shows zero effort. I still wonder how you came out with bg-secondary looking for how to change the background color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, it sounds like you're wanting a fallback color behind your image. Here's an example how to do this from: https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-using-fallback-colors/

```css
header {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url(plants.jpg);
  color: white;
}
```

Basically you first create your fallback background-color, then overwrite it with your background-image. If the background-image doesn't load, the background-color will stay.

For your second question about the text with the .aboutus-card-title class, you have your CSS selectors messed up. This is a good source for learning about selectors: https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/. If you want to select that class within main your selector should look like this:

```css
main .aboutus-card-title{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

In this case, you can probably leave off main and just have this:

```css
.aboutus-card-title{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

The only reason you would want to use the main selector here is if you wanted to style the .aboutus-card-title class differently if it's within main compared to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

These are two questions. I'd split them into two separate posts, makes it a bit easier to search.

For changing the background you can use:

```css
background-color: #82b5cf;
```

or

```css
background: #82b5cf;
```

For the centering of text on an image, you could use a combination of `position`, `top`, `left` and `transform`:

```css
.centered-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: I know this technique but nothing works for me.... hmm... i am uploading all the SASS, maybe i did something above wrong...:/.

Comment: maybe I should have clarified that the bottom css is for the paragraph element. Edited my answer.

Comment: have you read https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp ?